# YES or NO to semicolon in object events

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I've searched, but didn't find answer to this question. Should HTML DOM EVENTS, like `onChange`, `onSelect`, `onKeyUp`, `onFocus`, `onClick` etc. contain semicolon, example two lines below.

```
onChange="this.form.submit();" OR onChange="this.form.submit()"
```

"YES" or "NO" or "Doesn't Matter"

I guess it doesn't matter, but again, what's the best, most right to do?

Comment: inline event-handlers are so 90s.

Comment: @canon That's not the case, I just want to clarify that ";" DILEMMA to my self and few other colegues :P

Comment: And `onchange`, `onselect` etc. aren't events, they are event handlers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It doesn't matter.

The event handler attribute value is treated as a series of statements which are wrapped in a function signature similar to

```
 function (event) {
   with (event.target.ownerDocument) {
     with (event.target) {
       // attribute body goes here
     }
   }
 }
```

so you can put any group of [`SourceElement`](http://es5.github.com/#x14)s in the attribute value, and can leave off semicolons as per JavaScript's usual [semicolon insertion rules](http://es5.github.com/#x7.9).

Comment: There is also a `with(document)` around it.

Comment: @Dennis, forgot about that.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Never used it with semicolon, so I guess it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

No, you do not need a semicolon.
I do not know if it would work with it but without is fine.
If you need to know anything about web languages like HTML, CSS, or Javascript see www.w3school.com for reference or tutorials.
The link to the Javascript section is: http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp
A link to an example of what you were asking for is: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_popup.asp
This example uses the onclick you mentioned in your question.

Comment: Please don't link w3schools as a general reference (http://w3fools.com/). However, if you know one of their pages to be accurate _and_ pertains directly to the question at hand feel free to link it. That said, you're better off linking directly to the spec (http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm).

Answer (score 1):

It's really a matter of style; as with any JavaScript code snippet, you are allowed to omit unambiguous semicolons if you want to. (I prefer to put them in.)